# strcmp() not comparing

Tags: c, string, compare, strcmp

**Hello everybody,**
I'm a newbie and I'm doing a code that the principal aim is to print a number if two strings are equal. First string is obtained from a file and the second one is the string to be compared with.

***The code:***

```
int main()
{
char *string[2];
FILE *stream;
stream = fopen("REL","r");
if( (stream = fopen("REL","r")) == NULL)
{  
    printf("Can't open %s\n","REL");
    exit(1);
}
for(int i=0;i<92;i++)
{
    fscanf(stream,"%s",&string);
    if( strcmp("20", *string) == 0 )
    {
        printf("%d",20);
    }
}
fclose(stream);
}
```

and... when I tested on shell, it promp to me:

```
~/CM$ ./file2 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I might be doing a silly mistake. But, as a newbie, I cannot figure out whats is going wrong with the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string` is an unitialised array of 2 `char*`. The `fscanf` is attempting to write to memory where is should not. Declare `string` as an array of char:

```
char string[256];
```

and:

```
fscanf(stream, "%255s", string); /* Limit number of
                                    chars read to prevent buffer overrun. */
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
char string[128];
fscanf(stream, "%s", string);
```

and then:

```
if (!strcmp("20", string)) {
    /* The strings are equals */
}
```